# Identifying a specific value within a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary nested within a list. Looks like this so far...

```
mylist = [{'long_name': 1, 'type': 'unsure'}, {'long_name': 3, 'type': 'certain'}, {'long_name': 5, 'type': 'uncertain'}]
```

My goal is to identify the long_name value in the dictionary where the type key has a value of 'certain'. In this example I am looking to return the 3 in the second dictionary in myList.

I am going to have many different list/dict combos and the location of the correct dict is going to vary between them, which is why I need to come up with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the dictionary!

```
mylist = [{'long_name': 1, 'type': 'unsure'}, {'long_name': 3, 'type': 'certain'}, {'long_name': 5, 'type': 'uncertain'}]

for item in mylist:
    if item['type'] == 'certain':
        print(item['long_name']) # Or, add to another list
```

Fancy list comprehension (if you want to put it in a list)

```
mylist = [{'long_name': 1, 'type': 'unsure'}, {'long_name': 3, 'type': 'certain'}, {'long_name': 5, 'type': 'uncertain'}]
certain_names = [item['long_name'] for item in mylist if item['type'] == 'certain']
```